# My Java program can't end after I customise windowClosing Event in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In Netbeans, my program won't exit after I customise the windowClosingEvent.

I add the database connection closing instructions into the windowClosingEvent method to make sure that my database connection can be disconnected if user close the window instead of clicking disconnecting database button.

Then I manually add "system.exit(0);" within the closingEvent method generated by Netbeans. Now my program can finish. But I can't understand why it can't finish by itself if I add the windowClosing Event without explicitly turning off the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `WindowListener` interface or a `WindowAdapter` and you look at the original implementation in their `windowCloseing(e)` method, you will realise they did ***nothing*** for the implementation:

```
//Invoked when a window is in the process of being closed. The close     
//operation can be overridden at this point. 

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {}
```

Hence when you use it, you have to explicitly tell them what to do when you close the window. If don't override it, nothing will happen. If you do not have anything special to do other than terminating the program on closing the window, usually we write `System.exit(0);` in the overridden `windowClosing()` method.

**Example:**

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

---

*For your case, instead of just writing `System.exit(0)`, you may want to check whether the database connection is already closed:*

```
@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    //Check if database connection is closed
    //Close DB connection if open
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: @Eric_Lyn Take a look at my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Because closing the window doesn't mean that the program should be terminated. You should do in explicitly or you can configure you window to terminate program on window closing. frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);